# How to edit only the body shape of a character created in MetaHumans in Blender and export it

Tags: modeling, unreal-engine

Is there a way to edit only the body shape of a character created in MetaHumans in Blender and export it again to Unreal Engine 5, keeping the original rig and other detailed settings? I just want to reduce the puffiness of a woman's breasts created in MetaHumans.

Comment: Of course you can, what part are you struggling with exactly?